# WordPress Customiser not showing images in Media Library

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm in the process of building a custom area on my website. Basically I'm hooking the customizer up to a section on the front page.

So the idea is I go to 'Front Page Banner' via customiser, then select an image. When I click "Select" and go to "Media Library" the spinner just keeps turning and doesn't preview any other images to use.

```
 <?php
add_action( 'customize_register', 'pb_customizer_settings' );
function pb_customizer_settings( $wp_customize ) {

    $wp_customize->add_section( 'pb_front_page_banner' , array(
        'title'      => 'Front Page Banner',
        'priority'   => 30,
    ));

    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'banner_image' , array(
        'transport'   => 'refresh',
    ));

    $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Image_Control( $wp_customize, 'banner_image', array(
        'label' => 'Banner Image',
        'section' => 'pb_front_page_banner',
    )));
}
?>
```

Screenshots:

http://prntscr.com/jfung2

http://prntscr.com/jfunkz

http://prntscr.com/jfunss

Another thing I also need to know, is how do I set a default image on these sections?

Hope someone can help :)

Cheers

Comment: Did you check the browser console log to see if you have any js errors conflicting? Your customizer code looks good. Also you can set a default setting for your banner via your `add_setting(...)` section

Comment: @coletrain Thanks for your comment! I've managed to sort it, not exactly sure what I done to be honest but I think server-side caching has a part to play.